# converting a vector of chars to int in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm trying to do the following, but I'm having some trouble, and the only code I find on the web is for transforming strings into a number (basicly atoi), but I need something slightly different, e.g:

```
num1 Db '60','30'
num2 Db '2', '3'
num3 Db '*', '*'
```

Basicly I only need to transform the chars in the vector into numbers (separately), so I can do the operation marked by `num3` with `num1` and `num2`
as operators, as an example, I'll use my function that multiplies two numbers.
What I tried was:

```
MOV AX, DADOS
MOV DS, AX
MOV CX, 2
cycle:      
    CMP num3[si], 2Fh
    JE DIVISAO
    CMP num3[si], 2Ah
    JE MULTIPLICA
    CMP num3[si], 2Bh
    JE SOMA
    CMP num3[si], 2Dh
    JE SUBTRACAO
    inc si
    loop cycle

    JMP FIM
```

The multiply function:

```
MULTIPLICA PROC
    PUSH AX
    MOV AH, 0
    SUB num1[si], 48
    MOV AL, num1[si]
    SUB num2[si], 48
    IMUL num2[si]
    MOV DX, AX
    POP AX
    RET 
MULTIPLICA ENDP
```

I thought I only needed to subtract 48 to each position to make it into the correspondant number, but I guess there's something more to it. Thanks.
Edit: Did some ajustments, found out that it's only multiplying the first character, e.g: instead of 60*2, it's only doing 6*2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there definitely is something more to it. To turn a string into a byte, you can use something like this

```
; INPUT esi = a null-terminated string
; OUTPUT al = the number
str2byte:
    push cx
    mov cx, 0x0a00
    xor al, al
    .loop:
        mul ch
        mov cl, byte [esi]
        inc esi
        test cl, cl
        jz .end

        sub cl, 0x30
        add al, cl
        jmp loop
    .end:
    pop cx
    ret
```

... and to do the multiplication

```
num1 db '60', 0
num2 db '2', 0
multiply:
    mov esi, num1
    call str2byte
    mov ah, al

    mov esi, num2
    call str2byte

    imul ah

    ; the result is in AX
    ret
```

`str2byte` function requires `esi` to contain a null-terminated string to allow numbers like `100` or `255`, and therefore use the full range of a byte.

**Edit:**

If you were to use more elements, it would be only better to either use separate labels for all of them, e.g.

```
num1: db '60', 0
num2: db '4', 0
num3: db '7', 0
...
```

... or to align them, so you could smoothly get through

```
numbers: ; all of them are aligned to 4 bytes
    db '60', 0, 0
    db '4', 0, 0, 0
    db '120', 0
    ...

iterate:
    mov esi, numbers
    .loop:
       ; do something, like multiplying

       add esi, 4 ; increment by four bytes = one number
       jmp .loop
```

**Edit 2:**

However, the most elegant way to get through this kind of strings is to start where you've ended. That means, that you can use a chain for null-terminated string in a loop.

```
numbers:
    db '60', 0
    db '4', 0
    db '120', 0
    ...
    db '13', 0
    db 0

iterate:
    mov esi, numbers
    .loop:
        ; do something, let esi to be pointed at the beginning of every new string
        cmp byte [esi], 0x0 ; two zeroes can mean an end of strings / file
        jnz .loop ; again
```

Please note that

```
db 60
```

takes a single byte, while

```
db '60'
```

takes two bytes: one for '6' (`0x36`), and one for '0' (`0x30`)

Comment: if there are more elements in num1, as I mentioned in my example, I only need to add the index to mov esi, num1[si] and add a 0 to the end of the string, right? (and to num2 aswell)

Comment: @user35443 Your *str2byte* routine still needs a way to exit.

Comment: @user35443 I won't be able to use separate labels to all of them, because the vector has the input of a .txt file, in which the numbers are sequentially introduced into the vector

Comment: @user3144770 thanks, I forgot one `jz` there and one `inc` for esi

Comment: @Zetsuno in that case you may use the second approach, or a third one (wait for edit)

Comment: @user35443 I don't think I will be able to modify the code that transfers the .txt input into the vectors, it was provided by my college professor, and I don't have enough assembly knowledge to modify it to what I want, so I don't think I could do the change that aligns to 4 bytes... sorry

Comment: @Zetsuno That's why I added the Edit2, have a look. The format you've given is rather illogical, because there's no way to find out what the length of a `'string'` is, when they aren't null-terminated nor fixed in their length. Are you sure that's exactly the format? No `"` or `0`es at the end?

Comment: I think so, but I'm contacting my professor for more info, thanks for all your help tho, gonna try it then i'll net you know how it went!

Answer (score 0):

```
num3 DW '*', '*'
```

You need to define *num3* as byte because the `inc si` will give garbage on the 2nd iteration.

```
MOV DS, AX
```

Move this one outside the loop because AX will probably not have a segment value on subsequent iterations.

If the *multiplica* proc delivers a result in CX how then can you hope to continu the `loop` ?

Comment: It's outside of the cycle in my code, I just forgot to add it, and edited it on the wrong place, I'm gonna edit it so it matches my code.

Comment: Er.. forgot that detail, gonna change it to DX